# Theme Check reporting an incorrect theme slug and text domain

Tags: themes, theme-review

I was running my theme through Theme Check to check for WP.org compliance and it is giving me a warning that the theme is in the wrong directory. The specific warning is below:

> WARNING: Your theme appears to be in the wrong directory for the theme
>   name. The directory name must match the slug of the theme. This
>   theme's correct slug and text-domain is the-m-x.

However, my theme's text domain is set to `the-mx`, without the dash in between.

In style.css, I have:

```
/*
Theme Name: The M.X.
...
Text Domain: the-mx
*/
```

In functions.php:

```
function the_mx_setup() {
...
load_theme_textdomain( 'the-mx', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
...
?>
```

I am trying to figure out why the theme's slug is coming up as `the-m-x` instead. Also, would this prevent a theme from passing review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a quick look at

1. The theme name as defined in style.css, your's is "The M.X.", looks to me as if WordPress is interpreting the name as "the m x" because of the '.' between the m and the x.
2. What is the actual directory name that your theme is installed in?

Comment: the directory is also `the-mx`